# Create Schema in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I know it is ridiculously easy to create a schema in TSQL:

```
CREATE SCHEMA <Schema Name>
```

I had someone ask how to do this through SQL Server Management Studio. I couldn't locate the context menu item to replicate this in SSMS. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Object Explorer go to: Databases -> [YourDatabase] -> Security -> Schemas -> (right-click) New schema

[image: SSMS Schema]