# How to view schema of Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need a schema of Microsoft SQL Server like in this screenshot:

[image]

I created a schema according to [Create Schema in SSMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468967/create-schema-in-ssms) , but I can not view it in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

```
Databases -> [YourDatabase] -> Security -> Schemas -> (right-click) New schema
```

Where to view schema?

I go to Security -> Schemas -> myschemaname click on it and appears nothing.

Thanks for help, I am new to Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on screenshot I assume that you want database diagram.

`SSMS -> Object Explorer -> Database Name -> Database Diagram-> RC (Right Click) -> New Database diagram -> Add table`

More info: [Getting started with SQL Server database diagrams](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1816/getting-started-with-sql-server-database-diagrams/)

Comment: There is an error, if I do that, authentication method is SQL bases with "sa" account. Solved right click on database ->Properties->Files->owner->type in sa and click ok. After that diagram can be created.